# Como enumerar registros con una codición

Tags: sql-server

Estoy tratando de enumera los registros de una tabla de menor a mayo pero cuando la columna **n_meses_adeudo** sea 0 que la enumeración se reinicie y empiece nuevamente en 1.
E intenado con algo así

```
select  
    r.cuenta,
    r.año,
    r.mes,
    rd.concepto,
    rd.importe,
    r.n_meses_adeudo,
    r.porcentaje_de_recargo,
    case when n_meses_adeudo = 0 then 0 else ROW_NUMBER()over(order by r.cuenta asc ,r.año desc, r.mes desc) end as [row#]
from RecibosDetalle rd
inner join Recibos r on r.cuenta = rd.cuenta and r.año = rd.año and r.mes = rd.mes
order by r.cuenta asc ,r.año desc, r.mes desc
```

y el resultado es este

```
cuenta  año  mes concepto  importe  mesAdeudo  porcentaje row#
1      2021   2    44       629.16     3          2.5      1
1      2021   1    44       580.23     2          2.5      2
1      2020   12   44       421.23     1          2.5      3
1      2020   11   44       126.23     0          2.5      0
1      2020   10   44       100.23     2          2.5      5
1      2020   9    44       400.23     1          2.5      6
2      2021   2    44        171       0          2.5      0
2      2021   1    44       720.23     0          2.5      0
3      2021   2    44       215.04     0          2.5      0
3      2021   1    44       325.23     0          2.5      0
```

Lo que realmente necesito obtener es algo así

```
cuenta  año  mes concepto  importe  mesAdeudo  porcentaje row#
1      2021   2    44       629.16     3          2.5      1
1      2021   1    44       580.23     2          2.5      2
1      2020   12   44       421.23     1          2.5      3
1      2020   11   44       126.23     0          2.5      0
1      2020   10   44       100.23     2          2.5      1
1      2020   9    44       400.23     1          2.5      2
2      2021   2    44        171       0          2.5      0
2      2021   1    44       720.23     0          2.5      0
3      2021   2    44       215.04     0          2.5      0
3      2021   1    44       325.23     0          2.5      0
```

Si pudieran ayudarme o guiarme a que investigar se los agradecería!

Comment: Tendrias que usar un PARTITION BY y particionar por los campos que son como tu llave para que tu conteo vuelva a empezar , te anexo la liga donde puedes leer mas de ello https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Hola gracias por tu comentarios, el problema es que no hay una forma de identificar sobre que particionar.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner los datos como inserts con la definición de las tablas? Así no tendría que gastar tiempo en generar los datos de prueba.

Comment: USE [Prueba]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Recibos](
 [cuenta] [int] NOT NULL,
 [año] [smallint] NOT NULL,
 [mes] [tinyint] NOT NULL, 
 [porcentaje_de_recargo] [float] NOT NULL, 
 [n_meses_adeudo] [smallint] NULL)
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RecibosDetalle](
 [cuenta] [int] NOT NULL,
 [año] [smallint] NOT NULL,
 [mes] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
 [concepto] [smallint] NOT NULL,
 [importe] [float] NULL)
GO

Comment: INSERT [dbo].[Recibos] ([cuenta], [año], [mes], [porcentaje_de_recargo],  [n_meses_adeudo]) 
VALUES (1, 2021, 2, 2.5,3)
INSERT [dbo].[Recibos] ([cuenta], [año], [mes], [porcentaje_de_recargo],  [n_meses_adeudo]) 
VALUES (1, 2021, 1, 2.5,2)
INSERT [dbo].[Recibos] ([cuenta], [año], [mes], [porcentaje_de_recargo],  [n_meses_adeudo]) 
VALUES (1, 2020, 12, 2.5,1)
INSERT [dbo].[Recibos] ([cuenta], [año], [mes], [porcentaje_de_recargo],  [n_meses_adeudo]) 
VALUES (1, 2020, 11, 2.5,0)

Comment: INSERT [dbo].[Recibos] ([cuenta], [año], [mes], [porcentaje_de_recargo],  [n_meses_adeudo]) 
VALUES (1, 2020, 10, 2.5,2)
INSERT [dbo].[Recibos] ([cuenta], [año], [mes], [porcentaje_de_recargo],  [n_meses_adeudo]) 
VALUES (1, 2020, 9, 2.5,1)
INSERT [dbo].[Recibos] ([cuenta], [año], [mes], [porcentaje_de_recargo],  [n_meses_adeudo]) 
VALUES (2, 2021, 2, 2.5,0)
INSERT [dbo].[Recibos] ([cuenta], [año], [mes], [porcentaje_de_recargo],  [n_meses_adeudo]) 
VALUES (2, 2021, 1, 2.5,0)

Comment: INSERT [dbo].[Recibos] ([cuenta], [año], [mes], [porcentaje_de_recargo],  [n_meses_adeudo]) 
VALUES (3, 2021, 2, 2.5,0)
INSERT [dbo].[Recibos] ([cuenta], [año], [mes], [porcentaje_de_recargo],  [n_meses_adeudo]) 
VALUES (3, 2021, 1, 2.5,0)
INSERT [dbo].[RecibosDetalle] ([cuenta], [año], [mes], [concepto], [importe]) VALUES (1, 2020, 9, 44, 400.23)
INSERT [dbo].[RecibosDetalle] ([cuenta], [año], [mes], [concepto], [importe]) VALUES (1, 2020, 10, 44, 100.23)

Comment: INSERT [dbo].[RecibosDetalle] ([cuenta], [año], [mes], [concepto], [importe]) VALUES (1, 2020, 11, 44, 126.23)
INSERT [dbo].[RecibosDetalle] ([cuenta], [año], [mes], [concepto], [importe]) VALUES (1, 2020, 12, 44, 421.23)
INSERT [dbo].[RecibosDetalle] ([cuenta], [año], [mes], [concepto], [importe]) VALUES (1, 2021, 1, 44, 580.23)
INSERT [dbo].[RecibosDetalle] ([cuenta], [año], [mes], [concepto], [importe]) VALUES (1, 2021, 2, 44, 629.16)

Comment: INSERT [dbo].[RecibosDetalle] ([cuenta], [año], [mes], [concepto], [importe]) VALUES (2, 2021, 1, 44, 720.23)
INSERT [dbo].[RecibosDetalle] ([cuenta], [año], [mes], [concepto], [importe]) VALUES (2, 2021, 2, 44, 171)
INSERT [dbo].[RecibosDetalle] ([cuenta], [año], [mes], [concepto], [importe]) VALUES (3, 2021, 1, 44, 325.23)
INSERT [dbo].[RecibosDetalle] ([cuenta], [año], [mes], [concepto], [importe]) VALUES (3, 2021, 2, 44, 215.04)